# Definition of properly infinite projection in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $E$ be a projection in a von Neumann algebra $R$.  According to Kadison and Ringrose, $E$ is $\textit{properly infinite}$ if $E$ is infinite and for each central projection $P\in R$ either $PE=0$ or $PE$ is infinite.  But I've seen other definitions that require $PE$ to be infinite for each nonzero central projection $P\in R$.  It doesn't seem to me that these two definitions are equivalent, and if I am right then I believe there is a proof of a lemma in Kadison and Ringrose which is incorrect as written.

Comment: What Lemma is that?

Comment: @MartinArgerami The halving lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you've seen your second definition, but it is a weird choice. The spirit of "properly infinite" is that it has no finite part. Like, in $B(H)\oplus B(H)$, the projection $E_{11}\oplus I$ is not properly infinite because it has a finite part in the first block; this precludes the possibility of halving it. But saying that $0\oplus I$ is not properly infinite makes little sense, as it satisfies any property a *properly-infinite-in-the-second-sense* projection would have (other than having central carrier different than the identity).

As for the Halving Lemma in Kadison-Ringrose, the distinction is immaterial as it doesn't change the proof.

Comment: In the kadison-Ringrose proof of the halving lemma, why is it true that $(C_{E}-\sum Q_{A})E\neq 0$?

Comment: If $(C_E-\sum Q_a)E=0$ then you are done, because this gives you $E=\sum_aQ_aE$, and this is a pairwise orthogonal family of halvable projections.

Comment: Ah I see.  But do you agree that this part in the proof, where they claim that $(C_{E}-\sum{Q_{a}})E$ is properly infinite, is the only time they use the fact that $E$ Is properly infinite?

Comment: Yes. The idea of the proof is that an infinite projection always has a part that can be halved. If the projection is properly infinite, this can be iterated until you fill everything with halvable parts.

Comment: Thank you very much!